# Managed package installation and profiles

Tags: managed-package, profile, package-install

We have a managed package which would be used by a Marketing Director like profile. We have added permission sets to the profile to enable permissions to use the package.

We want the package to be installable for Marketing Managers/Directors.

Do we need to include a custom profile for a 'Marketing Manager/Director'?
If not, how would a system admin go about installing the app for other users? I assume they would have to assign the permission set and enable the app visibility for users. This seems tedious. Is it the recommended way to do this?

Also, How would additional profile installs be handled after the initial install? Say, the system admin installed the package for 'Standard User' profile and now wants to extend the package to 'Standard Platform User'? What would be the process for doing so?

Answer (score -1):

What you are saying is true - the org's sys-admin needs to manage the permission sets and profiles by himself.

Salesforce does not give the package creator the ability to control the org's security.

So the max you can do is add profiles and permission sets to your package and give instructions on how to manage them.

you can develop VF page to manage them but I think this would be an overkill, you should use the standard methods to do that.

*Keep in mind that profiles are not [upgradable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm), that means that once they where added to the org, the package installation cannot touch them.

Comment: Profile are not ever deployed to the org. They are only used during package install